# Adding JWT to cookie at login using flask security

Tags: react-native, flask-login, flask-security, flask-jwt-extended

Description: I'm trying to set the jwt token at login using
`flask_jwt_extended.set_access_cookies` and `flask_jwt_extended.set_refresh_cookies` but the issue is that I cannot set this at the `/login` endpoint because that is auto created by flask-security. What would be the best way to do this? Would the best way to do this be overriding the `/login` endpoint and set them there? Or can this be done in the `validate` method of `ExtendedLoginForm` even though I would need to add it to a request and not the `True` or `False` value that validate requires be returned?

End Result: Use regular cookies (to authenticate) to interact with flask related endpoints. Use JWT tokens (encoded in a cookie) to interact with a react-native compiled code.

Answer (score -1):

My first thought would be to step back - cookies (session) are an easy and secure way to manage all this - why have a JWT that is part of a cookie?

If you really want an Authentication-Token sent with every request - Flask-Security already offers that.
Now - to actually answer your question - You can attach to the "user-authenticated" signal and create your token and cookie there.